# Publishing Add-ons for Domain-Wide Installation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace, developer-console

I tried to Pre-install a Sheets add-on for all users in the domain.

For that purpose i referred to the steps provided here -> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/domain-wide

The add-on was successfully published to all users.

But the users are not able to use the said Add-on in all the sheets.

When trying to run the add-on only the "Help" sub-menu item is visible under the Add-on Menu as shown in image given below.

[image]

The above mentioned problem only gets resolved when i follow the below mentioned steps:

Add-ons -> Manage add-ons... -> Click on "Manage" button for the said Add-on -> Select "Use in this document" option as shown in images given below.

[image]

[image]

The problem gets resolved if and only if the user follows above mentioned steps and then reloads the spreadsheet in the browser.

Also, these steps are needed to be performed again to enable the Add-on for that particular spreadsheet if the user creates a fresh spreadsheet.

This operation is not needed for any Add-on that is available on the Chrome Web store or from the G-Suite Marketplace.

Is there any way in which any Sheets Add-on created using Google Apps Script can be published for domain wide installation and pre-installed in all users accounts and is available to be used in any Spreadsheet without having to Manage that Add-on for use in that particular spreadsheet?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share your Addon code as well to provide you more inputs

Comment: @abielita I dont seem to have mentioned anywhere that the Add-on is not working.

Comment: @DarpanSanghavi The Add-on has been pushed to end users successfully and it works just fine. I am not sure if you understood the problem i've described.

Comment: @SuyashGandhi: I've asked to share your code to provide you more inputs, I understand Addon has been published but users are not seeing Menu you have added in the Addon.

Comment: @DarpanSanghavi The users can see the Add-on when they install the Add-on for the first time.The problem arises when the user tries to use the Add-on in a new Spreadsheet and that problem is resolved when user follows the steps i've mentioned above.As for sharing the code, i dont feel there to be any problem in the code as If the menu is visible when the Add-on is first installed, it should be visible even if I open a new Spreadsheet because a code will not discriminate between a new spreadsheet and an old spreadsheet.But still, If you could share your email id I could email the code to you.